# Math.max(...) for JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two JodaTime objects and I wanted a method like so

```
// Return the latest of the two DateTimes
DateTime latest(DateTime a, DateTime b)
```

But I can't find such a thing. I could easily write it, but I'm sure JodaTime would have it somewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DateTime` implements `Comparable` so you don't need to roll you own other than doing:

```
DateTime latest(DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
  return a.compareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
}
```

or by using JodaTime API directly (which takes into account `Chronology` unlike `compareTo`):

```
DateTime latest(DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
  return a.isAfter(b) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had written something similar to your second example, but I was hoping to find something like this pre-written in a JodaTime utils class, instead of creating my own.

Answer (score 21):

As Jack pointed out, `DateTime` implements `Comparable`. If you are using Guava, the maximum of two dates (let's say `a` and `b`) can be determined by the following shorthand:

```
Ordering.natural().max(a, b);
```